# creating a matrix data class in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I am trying to create a Matrix to store data values.

this is what I have so far:

```
var Matrix = new function(rows, columns) {
var matrix = [[]];
var i,j;
this.matrix[i].length == columns;
this.matrix[i][j].length == rows;
if(matrix[i] === undefined){
    matrix[i] == 0;
}
}

Matrix.prototype = {
addValue: function (i,j,value) {
this.matrix[i][j].push(value);
console.log(this);
}
}

var m = new Matrix ();

m.addValue(1,1,"this is where I place it");
console.log(m);
```

I can't get rid of this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: `i` and `j` are never defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple Matrix could be:

```
Matrix = function() {
    this.rows = [];
}

Matrix.prototype = {

    put : function (row, column, value) {
        if (this.rows[row] === undefined) {
            this.rows[row] = [];
        }

        var row = this.rows[row];

        row[column] = value;

    },

    get : function (row, column) {
        return this.rows[row][column];
    }

}
```

Comment: However, if this is all it does, I would suggest calling it something else, reserving "Matrix" for the mathematical construct which also has certain operations (such as addition, multiplication, scalar multiplication, inversion, the taking of determinants, and many others.)

Comment: Naming things in a source code and naming things in real world are different things. If in a program, it is the only thing close to a real matrix, I see no reason not to call it a 'Matrix'. 
On the other hand, if you want to write a real mathematical matrix capable of all the computations, this a good basis I think, so it definitely can be a real Matrix later. As code always evolves it's good idea and also a common practice to name things of not what they are now, but what their creator wants them once to be.

Comment: My objection was that I didn't think this was a reasonable basis of a mathematical Matrix implementation.  Your sparseness is handled with undefined values rather than the mathematical zero.  (That may not really be important though.)  But your general point is well taken.  It really doesn't matter what you call it if it's not for public consumption and it won't interfere with other decision you have to make.